Why can't i filter using the inbuilt Content Approval Status field in power apps
I'm working on a power app (DS is SharePint list)|
I have content approval set to yes and have some approval wrkflow.
I have added a dropdown choice field that i would like to use to filter the data. All my other dropdown and text field work.
How do i compare to get the field value of the content approval status
But as you can see i'm getting the error /warning below highlighted in the screenshot
incompatible type for comparison. the type can't be compates control text


Any ideas what 'm missing and thanks in advance

'Content approval status1'.Value = ddlStatusfdl.Selected.Value

Thanks FredericDietrich but not sure youunderstood my issue. I'm having issue with the Content Approval Status field

show me how is setted your dropdown, and put ddlStatus.selected.value in a label to view wich value is setted in

Here you go
ddlStatusfld.Selected.Value = Blank(),
'Content approval status1'.Value = ddlStatusfld.Selected.Value
The   'Content approval status1'.Value gives me error : Value isn't recognised

have you rereshed your data source in left pane?

I  FredericDietrich yes i did.Also to let you know i'm using a table control :(
